# Cycles SSS Rendered image has a strange "noise" coloring artifacts

Tags: cycles-render-engine, subsurface-scattering

I am pretty new to blender and I was experimenting with a subsurface scattering material and lighting on an imported object. But when I've rendered an image of the object with a material that has a subsurface scattering, it shows this weird "noise" or "blur" on the surface of the object.

I've also rendered the same object without subsurface scattering and the problem seemed to be gone.

[image: This is the rendered image]

The current version of Blender that I use is 2.83 but I've seen this problem in previous versions.

Comment: What value do you have for your SSS strength? Does lowering it make any difference?

Comment: The strength of SSS is pretty low as it is 0.1, and I tried lowering it to the value of 0.05 but it didn't really make any differences. But what's weird that I found is that there's less noise when I increase it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by Blender trying very hard to render slight amounts of each shader. I.e. if you have a small amount of subsurfacing, and a whole lot of glass being shaded, it will be harder to render than an equal amount of both. Even trickier, if you have a large complex node setup with many different shaders mixed in.

My advice to fix this problem, if you want to keep the subsurface low, would be to increase your samplings for rendering by a large amount. Increase the rendering samples by about 100 per render, until you find a good amount. If that doesn't work, then you will have to either lower the denoising strength, which is what actually causes those spots to appear, or increase the subsurface strength.